# Using had said/said

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Can someone please tell me if the sentence below is correct?

> I whisper to myself some final words of validation, the same three
>   words I had said right before she passed away.

Is it necessary to use "had said"?

Comment: Since the event (I said) was completed before the following event (she passed away), it would be correct to use past perfect *had said*.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we use the Past Perfect to speak about something that happened before another action in the past, which is usually expressed by the past simple. So in your example when the first action precedes the second both are possible:

- I whisper to myself some final words of validation, the same three words I (had) said right before she passed away. - **Before** already implies the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, both

```
... the same three words I had said right ...
```

and

```
... the same three words I said right ...
```

are correct, carry the same meaning, and are common usage.